# Spring Jersey Test

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

I am currently working on a rest application with Jersey and spring mvc. Now one of my transaction implementation classes has an error that I have to correct. I'm totall confused as to how to go about it. This is it:

```
package com.compulynx.interview.transaction.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.compulynx.interview.models.Address;
import com.compulynx.interview.models.Person;
import com.compulynx.interview.transaction.TransactionBo;

public class TransactionBoImpl implements TransactionBo {

    private List<Person> persons;

    public TransactionBoImpl() {
        this.persons = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        //your code here
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> createPerson(Person person) {
        //your code here
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> updatePerson(Person person) {
        //your code here
    }

}
```

//Transaction Bo.java

```
package com.compulynx.interview.transaction;

import java.util.List;

import com.compulynx.interview.models.Person;

public interface TransactionBo{

List<Person> getPersons();

List<Person> createPerson(Person person);

List<Person> updatePerson(Person person);
```

}

any help ?

Comment: It's not clear what problem do you have to correct. Compilation errors, exceptions, prototyping?